# Vue, getting sender element on change event

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, single-page-application, vuetify.js

Im just learning VUE and I've been trying something as simple as getting the sender-element of a @change event.
My markup looks like this

```
<v-text-field label="Takst 1" ref="tarif1Input" v-model="Income.Tariffs[0]" field="@SecurityHelper.SimpleCrypt("CUST_TARIFF1")" @@change="tariffChanged"></v-text-field>
```

and the event is wired up like this:

```
methods: {
                tariffChanged: function (newVal) {
                    var $s = $(this.$refs.tarif1Input.$el).find('input');
                    var newValue = $s.getValue();

                    $.post('/api/Budget/SaveTariff', {
                        FieldKey: $s.attr('field'),
                        Value: newVal
                    }).done(function () {
                        app.populateIncome();
                    });
                }
}
```

The only way I've managed to get the sending element is by using refs and using this :
`this.$refs.tarif1Input.$el` but is that really the best way to do this? cant I somehow get the sending element through the functions arguments.

It really seems like a step backwards from wiring this up manually in javascript; kind of like overusing global variables.

I'm using vuetifyjs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look on this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/55e46mn3/4/

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" @change="tariffChange"/>
</div>
```

---

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    methods: {
        tariffChange(event) {
           const inputTarget = event.target;
           console.log(inputTarget.value)
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Well in My case the only argument is the new value.

..but you got me in the right direction, that id I used @change.native("[function]"), it worked as you described..

With a slight change to your suggestion, the ansver is correct.